# What does *monte* mean in the term *three-card-monte* game?

Tags: word-meaning, adjectives, nouns

What does ***monte*** mean in the term “*three-card-monte*” game? I have looked up the word in dictionaries but I'm afraid I couldn't find any applicable answer.

> I was not long set, before my friend returned. He looked pale and rather old, refused to hear of food, and called for tea.
>
> “I suppose all's up?” said I, with an incredible sinking.
>
> “No,” he replied; “I've pulled it through, Loudon—just pulled it through. I couldn't have raised another cent in all 'Frisco. People don't like it; Longhurst even went back on me; said **he wasn't a three-card-monte man**.”
>
> “Well, what's the odds?” said I. “That's all we wanted, isn't it?”
>
> “Loudon, I tell you I've had to pay blood for that money,” cried my friend, with almost savage energy and gloom. “It's all on ninety days, too; I couldn't get another day—not another day.

From *[The Wrecker](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/The_Wrecker_(Stevenson)/Chapter_10https://)* (chapter ten) by Robert Luois Stevenson

Comment: monte  Origin early 19th century: Spanish, literally ‘mountain’, also ‘heap of cards left after dealing’.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Only there is no heap of cards in three-card monte.

Comment: @Lambie - lots of borrowings get their meaning changed in the process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chambers has "three-card monte" "A mexican three-card trick", where "monte" is a spanish-american card game. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monte_Bank

Comment: *Monte* seems to be a denotation of a specific Mexican game, so *monte* seems to be a Spanish word, right? Hence *monte* in Spanish means *mountain* in my opinion. I don't see any correlation between this game and a mountain, do you?

Comment: As I said, in the context of the question "monte" is a spanish-american card game. The question of why it is called monte in Spanish seems to be answered above ... a little off-topic but welcome none the less.

Comment: @ timchessish - It seems to be but it isn't. The word *monte* has surely a meaning that correlates to this game in my opinion.

Comment: I've found the answer now: *The remaining stack of cards, called the "monte", is placed face-down in front of the dealer. Sometimes a monte box was used to hold the monte*:  *Monte* in English means the deck or stack of cards though in the three-card-monte game I can't detect any card deck. - Is it possible to create this as an applicable answer?

Comment: The remaining stack of cards, called the "monte", is placed face-down in front of the dealer. Sometimes a monte box was used to hold the monte: Monte in English means the deck or stack of cards though in the three-card-monte game you can't detect any card deck.

Comment: @philphil - a pile, stack, or 'mountain' of cards.

Comment: In the Spanish or Mexican Monte gambling card game the remaining stack of cards, called the "monte", is placed face-down in front of the dealer. Sometimes a monte box was used to hold the monte: Monte in English means the deck or stack of cards. However, you can't detect any card deck in the three-card-monte game. This denotation is borrowed from the Spanish Monte game.

Comment: philphil - exactly as i said in my answer. Any idea why it was marked down?

Comment: @timchessish - maybe, possibly, it's because your answer is very short, just gives a Wikipedia link, and does not actually say anything about what 'monte' means.

Comment: @ timchessish - I didn't downvote it actually. I also wonder why the question was downvoted.

Comment: @philphil Probably someone downvoted the answer because it is incomplete, the game referred to in the novel is played with three cards but the Wikipedia article which timchessish linked to, talks about the two-card version (Mexican) and the four-card version (Spanish). Maybe a link to Chambers Dictionary would have helped clear up the ambiguity? Oh, and the answerer didn't explain what *monte* meant. Oh, and another thing he didn't capitalize the words "Mexican card trick" or "Spanish-American". The whole answer looks rushed. -1 from me.

Comment: …`exactly as i said in my answer. Any idea why it was marked down?` Where did you mention deck or stack of cards **in your answer**? Where did you say *monte* is a direct borrowing from the Spanish term? Where did you explain the rules of the game?

Comment: And yet, this low-quality answer has now received a third upvote. It would be interesting to know *why*.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I suppose the upvoters have made some inference or other, possibly even the intended inferences.

Answer (score 1):

In the context of playing cards, the Spanish word ***monte*** refers to the **pile of cards** that are not dealt out to the players.

In the text, the quote refers to Mr Longhurst who refuses to bid higher than a certain sum of money saying he was not a  *three-card-monte man*, someone who could afford to lose money in a risky bet. The [three-card monte](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-card_monte) is in fact a scam, a common [confidence trick](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/confidence-trick) to trick people out of their money.

There are three cards in the game, one of which is the target card; e.g., the queen of hearts.  First, the dealer shows the cards face up on a table, then the cards are placed face down, and he proceeds to deftly switch them in front of a gathering crowd. When  the swapping stops,  the dealer asks if anyone in the crowd wants to *bet* where the target card is. A player bets money against the "bank" (the dealer) that they can pick the right card. If the player is not part of the scam team, he (or she) will inevitably lose every game they bet money on as the stake keeps getting higher and higher.